# Difference between assemble vs assembleDebug vs assembleRelease

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, bitrise

I am trying to learn [bitrise](https://www.bitrise.io) platform. As of now I don't know what exactly a use of this platform also. Anyways while I was doing setup and it is asking for to select `gradle-task` to run.

Does anyone know what is the difference between assemble vs assembleDebug vs assembleRelease ?

Did anyone get a chance to try this platform ever in the mobile application ?

[image]

Comment: In short Bitrise is a continuous integration and deployment tool, with a mobile focus. Other than CI/CD you can also use it to automate tasks you'd do manually before, like submitting builds to distribution services (HockeyApp, Google Play, TestFlight,..), sending emails or Slack messages, related to the build. There's also a command line tool (https://www.bitrise.io/cli) which you can use to run builds/tasks locally on you Mac/PC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An Android project has at least two outputs: a debug APK and a release APK. Each of these has its own anchor task to facilitate building them separately:

1. assemble
2. assembleDebug
3. assembleRelease

They both depend on other tasks that execute the multiple steps needed to build an APK. The assemble task depends on both, so calling it will build both APKs.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: It is not correct. It depends by buildTypes defined in the build.gradle file. Debug and release are defined by default if you don't specify them in the build.gradle file, but you can override them.